# Passing multiple values to a function inside another function

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I have a function that calls another function and uses its values. I've searched and found (and prove) that you have to do it like this:

```
SELECT * from TABLE(FUNCTION proc1()) as tab_proc1(val1, val2);
```

Until there, everything okay, but my function (in this case proc1()) HAS values that I need to pass and since that sentence is in another function I need to assign the results to some values — like:

```
select * into impo_ori, impt_ori, impo_des 
from Table(procedure fc_moneda(cmon, importe, cmon_ori, cmon_des));
```

When I execute the function which is:

```
create procedure ala(cmon integer, importe decimal, cmon_ori integer, cmon_des integer)
returning boolean;

    define impo_ori, impt_ori, impo_des decimal;
    define ver boolean;

    select * into impo_ori, impt_ori, impo_des
    from Table(procedure fc_moneda(cmon, importe, cmon_ori, cmon_des));

    //continues... 

    return ver;

end procedure;
```

But takes the variables inside fc_moneda (like cmon, importe...etc) as if they were values and not variables. That sentence just works if I pass the values
like:

```
select * into impo_ori,impt_ori,impo_des
from Table(procedure fc_moneda(1, 100, 1, 2));
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'll have to do some experimenting.  The problem isn't so much passing the values to another function — the problem is passing values into a function used in the TABLE clause of a SELECT statement (in this case).  That is, if you were calling another stored procedure in another context, or even `fc_moneda()` outside of the SELECT statement, there'd be no problem whatsoever passing the values.  I'm not sure (yet) what's up with it inside the SQL, though I can make some guesses — but I'm not prepared to share those until I've experimented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to **10.00.UC1**, the best I could do was **11.50.FC9**.

I've tried the next example and it worked has expected:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ dbaccess -e test test.sql

Database selected.

CREATE TABLE tab1 (
    col1 INTEGER
);
Table created.

INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (1);
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (2);
1 row(s) inserted.

CREATE TABLE tab2 (
    col1 INTEGER
);
Table created.

CREATE FUNCTION sp1(arg1 INTEGER)
RETURNING INTEGER;

        DEFINE var INTEGER;

        SELECT col1 + 10 INTO var
        FROM tab1
        WHERE col1 = arg1;

        RETURN var;

END FUNCTION;
Routine created.

CREATE PROCEDURE sp2(arg1 INTEGER)

    DEFINE var INTEGER;

        CALL sp1(arg1) RETURNING var;

        INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES (var);

END PROCEDURE;
Routine created.

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp2(1);
Routine executed.

SELECT * FROM tab2;

       col1

         11

1 row(s) retrieved.

CREATE PROCEDURE sp3(arg1 INTEGER)

    DEFINE var INTEGER;

        SELECT * INTO var
        FROM TABLE(procedure sp1(arg1));

        INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES (var);

END PROCEDURE;
Routine created.

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp3(2);
Routine executed.

SELECT * FROM tab2;

       col1

         11
         12

2 row(s) retrieved.

Database closed.

[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

Looking at your tests seems like the only valid way is to use a `CALL`. But there is another way you can try, passing the argument to a temporary table:

```
[infx1150@tardis ~]$ dbaccess -e test test.sql

Database selected.

CREATE TABLE tab1 (
        col1 INTEGER
);
Table created.

INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (1);
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (2);
1 row(s) inserted.

CREATE TABLE tab2 (
        col1 INTEGER
);
Table created.

CREATE FUNCTION sp1(arg1 INTEGER)
        RETURNING INTEGER;

        DEFINE var INTEGER;

        SELECT col1 + 10 INTO var
        FROM tab1
        WHERE col1 = arg1;

        RETURN var;

END FUNCTION;
Routine created.

CREATE PROCEDURE sp1(arg1 INTEGER)

        DEFINE var INTEGER;

        CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp1(
            col1 INTEGER
        ) WITH NO LOG;

        INSERT INTO tmp1 VALUES (arg1);

        SELECT sp1(col1) INTO var
        FROM tmp1;

        INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES (var);

END PROCEDURE;
Routine created.

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp1(1);
Routine executed.

SELECT * FROM tab2;

       col1

         11

1 row(s) retrieved.

Database closed.

[infx1150@tardis ~]$
```

Regarding the returned more than one row, if it is an expected behavior then you have to change your procedure to treat every row returned, something like:

```
[infx1150@tardis ~]$ dbaccess -e test test.sql

Database selected.

CREATE TABLE tabs(
    col1 INTEGER
);
Table created.

CREATE FUNCTION series(lim INTEGER)
RETURNING INTEGER;
        DEFINE i INTEGER;
        FOR i IN (1 to lim)
                RETURN i WITH RESUME;
        END FOR;
END FUNCTION;
Routine created.

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_i_tabs(lim INTEGER)
        DEFINE var INTEGER;

        FOREACH EXECUTE FUNCTION series(lim) INTO var
                INSERT INTO tabs VALUES (var);
        END FOREACH
END PROCEDURE;
Routine created.

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_i_tabs(5);
Routine executed.

SELECT * FROM tabs;

       col1

          1
          2
          3
          4
          5

5 row(s) retrieved.

Database closed.

[infx1150@tardis ~]$
```

Comment: Besides... I came to that conclusion because when I call the procedure  (with the original statements) gave this error: Column (cmon) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined). So I tested with fc_moneda(1, importe, cmon_ori, cmon_des) and gave same error with the nex variable (Column (importe) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined)